# looping value inside function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop the value inside an excel function. I tried it but not getting exact value.

I have a counter that is getting the cell value from D1 and looping it to last. I would like to increment "**counter**" from 1 till the cell value in the given function
"=mx.Name(""control"", counter)". The code is below.

```
   Range("D1").Select

   Dim counter As Integer
   counter = 1

   Do While counter <= Cells(1, "D")
     Cells(counter, "A").Value = "=mx.Name(""control"", counter)"
    counter = counter + 1

   Loop
```

Currently the counter variable is not incrementing, its writing 'counter' in excel. Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable to string formula:

```
Cells(counter, "A").Value = "=mx.Name(""control""," & counter & ")"
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefano Balzarotti , it worked perfectly.

Comment: PUSer, since both Stefano Balzarotti and @麦伟锋 gave the same answer but the latter was "faster", you should accept 麦伟锋 answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Cells(counter, "A").Value = "=mx.Name(""control"", counter)"
```

change to

```
Cells(counter, "A").Value = "=mx.Name(""control"", " & counter & ")"
```